# How to update this old codes about LibGDX Controllers?

Tags: libgdx

I blueprint an opensource game project.And when I copy and paste this class into my project
 `import com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers;`does not exist. I think this code is very old. And because of this `getControllers()` method does not work.

How can I update this code. I put this class below.

```
package com.good.game.controls;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers; // this import does not exist

public class InputController {

    public static final InputController instance = new InputController();

    public InputController () {
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    }

    public boolean controllerEnabled() {
        return (Controllers.getControllers().size > 0); //Cannot resolve Controllers
    }

    public boolean axisLeft() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getAxis(8) == -1 //Cannot resolve Controllers
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT));
    }

    public boolean axisRight() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getAxis(8) == 1//Cannot resolve Controllers
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT));
    }

    public boolean axisUp() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getAxis(9) == -1)//Cannot resolve Controllers
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP);
    }

    public boolean axisDown() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getAxis(9) == 1)//Cannot resolve Controllers
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN);
    }

    public boolean buttonA() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getButton(96) || //Cannot resolve Controllers
                Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Z));
    }

    public boolean buttonB() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getButton(97)||//Cannot resolve Controllers
                Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.C));
    }

    public boolean buttonX() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getButton(99) ||//Cannot resolve Controllers
                Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.X));
    }

    public boolean buttonY() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getButton(100));//Cannot resolve Controllers
    }

    public boolean rightTrigger() {
        return (controllerEnabled() && Controllers
                .getControllers().get(0).getAxis(7) == 1);//Cannot resolve Controllers
    }

    public boolean closeButton() {
        return Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK) ||
                Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.ESCAPE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the gdx-controllers extension to your dependencies. It was extracted from the main project.